# Populate new chart on ReportViewer1 with SQL query information

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, charts

I am completely new to Charts in asp.net so bear with me, I have been reading multiple multiple webpages on how bind data to the charts but I still can not get anything to show up.

I know this probably isnt the first instance of this question, but I cant figure this out to save my life. Im hoping with a little nudge I wont need any help on this topic after this.

Say I have a dropdown and this drop down has two items in it. On Dropdown_IndexChange it will change the data source of chart1 that is located in ReportViewer (The database is going to be local).

Index 0 creates a bar chart with the SQL Command: 
"SELECT [SWversion:], [Batt_Wifi:], [Batt_Standby:], [Batt_OnCall:] FROM Amaze"

where SWVersion are the names of the series and the other 3 are the data.

Index 1 creates a line chart with the sql command:
"SELECT [SWversion:], [Wifi_Pref_IC:], [Wifi_Pref_NC:], [Wifi_Only_IC:], [Wifi_Only_NC:] FROM Amaze"

SWVersion works the same way here as well.

How can I get these charts to show up and how can I attach SWVersion names to the series.

The code I am trying to work with is this:

```
    Chart1.DataSource = Nothing
    Chart1.Visible = True
    Dim newsqlcommand As String = "SELECT [Batt_Wifi:], [Batt_Standby:], [Batt_OnCall:] FROM Amaze"
    Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connexstring)
        con.Open()      
        Dim myCommand = New SqlDataAdapter(newsqlcommand, con)
        Dim ds = New DataSet()
        myCommand.Fill(ds)
        Chart1.DataSource = myCommand
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End Using
    Chart1.DataBind()
```

I know this is only one of the SQL Commands but Im still trying to figure out how it works. I don't recieve an error, but with this I can't even get a chart to draw.

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: I've never used this before, but wouldn't you want to set the datasource for the chart to the dataset that you filled rather than the command that you used to fill the dataset?

Comment: Either way, I still cant get anything work, and Im not receiving any errors so I have no idea how to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like always I was making this waaaay harder then it had to be.

The easiest way to solve this problem is just to graph the information that has already been populated in the GridViews.

So whether your gridviews are tied to your database or not, it really doesnt matter, just call a sub or a function that populates the charts with the information that has already been queried.

piece of cake.

Zach